# Why does len(point_str) return 1?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys
string_input = "6\n212 132322\n212 21\n65 56\n32 3\n3232 32\n313 13\n0"
# a two dimensional array to store points
points = []
for line in string_input.split("\n"):
    # split the inputed line using space to divide x and y coordinate
    points_str = line.split(" ")
    point_coordinate = []
    if len(points_str) != 1:
        for val in points_str:
            point_coordinate.append(int(val))
            points.append(point_coordinate)
        print(str(points))
print(len(points_str))
```

Why does the len(points_str) return 1? I am also very confused why 1 != 1 continues to perform the rest of the code.

Comment: Do you realize there's more than one value of `points_str` involved here?

Comment: Yes, I added the print(len(points_str)) to check what the length was, which was 1.

Comment: That's only printing the length of the final value assigned to `points_str`, not any of the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

First your loop run through all iterations, then you print out `len(points_str)`. Now `points_str` gets a new value in each iteration, but since you only print at the end, you get the length of the *last* value that  `points_str` was assigned. This is the last element of `string_input.split("\n")`, which is `'0'`. The length of `'0'` is indeed 1.

Try moving the line

```
print(len(points_str))
```

inside of the loop (that is, just add four spaces) and check the output. You should also try to print out `points_str`, not just its length.

Answer (score -1):

Well, because it's of length 1. At least in your first iteration.

Your first line is "6", so points_str is ["6"], which has a length of 1.

You should really use a debugger.

Comment: Im not very familiar with debuggers, could you explain?

Comment: It is the result of the last iteration, not the first, that gets printed.

Comment: The last line is 0. Use a debugger.